# 4 step area of a solid of revolution

Tags: calculus

I have been working on this problem all night and its driving me crazy no matter which way I try to tackle it I just cant seem to nail down the right answers even though my work seems correct. would someone try walking me through the problem so I can see just what you did to get each answer?

Let S be the region of the xy-plane bounded above by the curve $x^3y=729$, below by the line $y=1$, on the left by the line $x=9/2$, and on the right by the line $x=9$. Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating S around

$(a)$ the $x$-axis  $161.164$ You are correct
$(b)$ the line $y=1$  $245.044$   Submit Answer  Incorrect.
$(c)$ the $y$-axis  $245.044$   Submit Answer  Incorrect
$(d)$ the line $x=9/2$

as you can see its multiple steps. I did fine rotating around the $x=$axis but rotating around the y axis or a line other than the axis is just beyond my capability. no matter how I integrate or change variables from x to y and even graphing and looking at it closely I still couldn't do these last three parts. can someone please step me through this? I am close on the y axis but the $x=9/2$ is tough and the y=1 is horrible for me. thank you very much